# How to allocate array of IntPtr [] in unmanaged memory?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-management, intptr, alloc

To allocate memory in managed code i use:

```
IntPtr [] params_list_n = new IntPtr [5];
```

But  for unmanaged memory i use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`
And I do not understand how, in this case to allocate memory for the array.

Ideally I want to use the function call `Marshal.GetNativeVariantForObject (o, params_list_n[i]);`
For each element of the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating unmanaged memory using [Marshal.AllocHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx) is simple.

```
IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
```

If you need to calculate the amount of space you can use [Marshal.SizeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa.aspx).

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
```

You will also need to enable `unsafe code` in your project for this to run.

1. Right click on your project and select `Properties`.
2. Open the `Build` tab.
3. Select `Allow unsafe code`.

Comment: Thank you. Tell me more how to copy the memory from unmanaged to unmanaged.
Marshal.Copy not be suitable for this purpose. As I understand

Answer (score 4):

The array will be a pointer to the elements.  You use it the same way:

```
IntPtr results = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(5 * IntPtr.Size);
```

Comment: @Mixer fixed - sorry, went fast

Comment: I forgot about `IntPtr.Size`. Kudos. :)

Comment: Thank you.
But I can not access the individual elements of the array.
This is not quite what I need.

I want to use the function call Marshal.GetNativeVariantForObject (o, params_list_n[i]);
For each element of the array.